# How to run web flask using Live-sever on Vs Code or similar?

Tags: flask, visual-studio-code, web

I am developing a Flask website and I want it to run as a virtual website (Http:....), and I already know the Live-server utility, but I don't know how to use it to run Web Flask (or in a similar way). Thanks for everyone's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live server is use for running static based website. If you want to run Flask app at production you should deploy the website on Heroku or others cloud service platforms.

Answer (score 0):

you can use debug=True
but don't forget to change it to False before upload it to the host to avoid any hacker attack

if **name** == "**main**":
app.run(debug=True)